# Update View Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

I have an entry box, where the user can enter his math expression. If it is not valid, a warning view will be displayed under it for 5 seconds, disappearing after that. If found out that it is not valid, the ShowWarning method is called

```
CustomViews.ValidExpressionWarning.Instance.ShowWarning();
//CustomViews is a namespace
```

ValidExpressionWarning being this class:

```
 public  partial class ValidExpressionWarning : ContentView
    {

        public static ValidExpressionWarning Instance;//its only instance is created in xaml
        public  Action ShowWarning;
        Timer timer = new Timer(5000);
        public ValidExpressionWarning()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Instance = this;
            SetEvents();
        }
        private void SetEvents()
        {
            timer.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) => { this.IsVisible = false; timer.Enabled = false; };
            ShowWarning += () => { this.IsVisible = true; timer.Enabled = true; };
        }
    }
```

When ShowWarning() is first called, the view appears as expected, and I assume the timer starts too. But after 5 seconds, nothing happens. It's like its Elapsed event is not even invoked. So the warning view just remains on the screen. Does it have anything to do with not calling the PropertyChanged event?As far as I know INotifyPropertyChanged is only used with binding.Thanks.

Comment: have you used the debugger to verify if Elapsed is firing?  If it is, the most likely issue is that you need to force `IsVisible = false;` to run on the UI thread.  You can use Essentials MainThread to do this.

Comment: It may has something to do withe the thread you are running on. Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/ios-ui/ui-thread and try to invoke the call.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg - No, that is iOS-specific code. The question refers to a cross-platform view, so should use cross-platform code. `Device.BeginInvokeOnManThread(() => { ... });`

Comment: @Jason I didn't know much about multi-threading until today, only about asynchronous programming.Anyway, on what other thread can the isVisible = false; if I'm not creating any other?

Comment: honestly, it would take one line of code to test this theory.  Just do it and see if it fixes your problem.